# Ruby Unit Testing Get Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, get, functional-testing, ruby-on-rails-2

I am pulling my hair out trying to expand the testing coverage for an existing Rails 2.3 app.

They are using a unit:test framework. I am really having trouble wrapping my head around how to debug the `get` method that appears a lot. Here is an example:

```
   get(:results,
        { # params
          :s => "college",
          :alt_iframes => iframes_param,
          :site_version => ApplicationController::VERSION_GOOGLE.to_i
        },
        { # session
          :arrival_id => 3,
          :arrival_quality => test_quality,
          :tid => test_tid,

        })
```

When it works, it is pretty self-evident what is going on. However, when it doesn't work, I have a lot of trouble debugging what is going wrong.

Is there anyway to understand what exact URL a call like this equates to?  Or is it possible to make a call of this form instaed `get("localhost:3000`").

I am having even finding documentation when I do a google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about a controller test, then `get` doesn't call a URL at all. It just directly calls the action in the controller you are testing. It works differently if you are talking about an integration test... and nobody should be calling get in a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on the method that the test is testing and if the application is RESTful or not.

For instance, if you're doing this in a comments controller, Rails will use the routes that are setup to determine that this is testing /comments.

If it's a put, it'll know you're testing update with /comments/:id.